# How to do audio recording on Android and make the audio and video time synchronization

Tags: android, audio, video, synchronization

I am trying to build a video system. Now I've finished capture the data from camera, encode the data using [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html). I also find that I could use the [MediaMux](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html) to do the Mux job. But I don't know how to record the audio and how to keep the audio and video time synchronization. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The `BufferInfo` passed to `writeSampleData()` includes the presentation time stamp.  So you need to ensure that all audio and video data has the correct time stamps in the same timeline.

Comment: Did you ever find out a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you wish to use [MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html). And do not mess with muxing. You'll get ready video file.

Comment: Thank you for that. But I want to have the access to the data captured by the device. So I won't use MediaRecorder.

Comment: @BrendonTsai did you ever find out a solution?

Comment: @OxSina fadden provides a solution, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835655/does-mediacodec-in-android-support-audio-encodec/20843791?noredirect=1#20843791.